# How can I run two instances of WhatsApp on a Mac?

Tags: mac, whatsapp.app

I have two phone numbers for two purposes and I would like to run two native WhatsApp clients in parallel on my Mac.

I don't want to use the browser (or two browser windows) since I prefer the native Mac OS apps.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply open terminal and run this command:

```
/Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/MacOS/WhatsApp /secondary
```

Two remarks:

1. The app seems to crash if you subsequently close the terminal (even if you use &) so keep your terminal open. Sudo may solve this ([as seen here](https://www.compulaptop.com/how-to-run-2-whatsapp-accounts-at-the-same-time-mac/)) but I didn't really try.
2. If anyone knows how to make it launch from Spotlight, please share your ideas. I would love to improve on this method and make it easier to use.

Comment: Plain Sudo should not be used here as tha app runs as a user. I guess the two WhatsApp apps need to be run as different users. If so create another user and sudo that app

Comment: No more works with the latest version of Whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

From Finder, copy Whatsapp app into Whatsapp2

Comment: Actually this is not working, copy app brings window of original applicaiton.

Comment: Yes it works, it becomes two apps. Select WhatsApp, Cmd-C, Cmd-V. Rename "Copy of WhatsApp" to "WhatsApp2". Unfortunately it doesn't work on Beta Multi-device.

Comment: ‎Error: Another instance of WhatsApp is already running - ‎‎You can not run two instances of WhatsApp. Please quit the other instance and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this option which is working nicely so far:

WhatsApp native app + [MenubarX](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/menubarx/id1575588022?mt=12) (WhatsApp Web)

MenubarX is basically a browser that lives in the Mac menu bar with each web app having its own icon. So while this isn't native, as it does use whatsapp web, you get a dedicated icon in the top menu bar with notification indication and it looks just like native whatsapp. Unlike whatsapp web, you don't have to look through your open browser tabs to find it.

Comment: How does MenubarX help? Please [edit] and expand upon your answer, as it isn't at all clear how it provides a solution.